# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2012 Express using osql or other 3rd party client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express, and is able to **successfully** connect using SQL Server Management Studio and create databases.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

However, when I try to connect to through the osql client, I get the following error:

[image]

I also notice that there the protocols list is **empty** inside the **SQL Server Network Interfaces** section of SQL Server Configuration Manager, though the SQL Native Client 11.0 section do have the protocols. Not sure, if this behaviour has anything to do with the issue seen:

[image]

Comment: `osql` and `isql` are long deprecated - since SQL Server **2005**, you should use `sqlcmd` instead

Comment: tried sqlcmd with no much luck. I'm using the command line tool to narrow down / troubleshoot the issue. Any thoughts why the "SQL Server Network Interfaces" section is empty?

Comment: The password is blank? ;).